# How do I calculate the number of ticks per measure from a MIDI file

Tags: midi, javax.sound.midi

I am trying to calculate the number of ticks per measure (bar) from a MIDI file, but I am a bit stuck.

I have a MIDI file from which I can extract the following information (provided in meta messages):

`@0:` Time signature: `4/4`, Metronome pulse: `24 MIDI clock ticks per click`, Number of 32nd notes per beat: `8`

There are two tempo messages, which I'm not sure are relevant:

`@0:` Microseconds per quarternote: `400000`, Beats per minute: `150.0`

`@1800:` Microseconds per quarternote: `441176`, Beats per minute: `136.0001450668214`

From trial and error, looking at the Note On messages, and looking at the MIDI file in Garageband, I can 'guess' that the number of ticks per measure is `2100`, with a quarternote `525` ticks.

My question is: can I arrive at the `2100` number using the tempo information that was provided above, and if so how? Or have I not parsed enough information from the MIDI file and is there some other control message that I need to look at?

Comment: The tempo messages are not relevant. You need the ticks-per-quarter value from the file header.

Comment: You are right. I forgot about the header and was just looking at the tracks. The header gives `PPQ` as `480` which means I overshot a little with `525`. If you wish to reframe your comment as an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: I'm to lazy to look up the documentation; just answer yourself with the working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following Java 11 code to extract the ticks per measure. This assumes 4 quarter notes per bar.

```
public MidiFile(String filename) throws Exception {

    var file = new File(filename);
    var sequence = MidiSystem.getSequence(file);
    System.out.println("Tick length: " + sequence.getTickLength());
    System.out.println("Division Type: " + sequence.getDivisionType());
    System.out.println("Resolution (PPQ if division = " + javax.sound.midi.Sequence.PPQ + "): " + sequence.getResolution());
    System.out.println("Ticks per measure: " + (4 * sequence.getResolution()));

}
```